# What can I do to fix my code with this HLSL error about array references in loops?

Tags: arrays, unity-game-engine, hlsl, compute-shader

I've got an HLSL file with the following code:

```
struct particle
{
    float2 pos;
    float next_pos;
    float angle;
};
particle nearby[32];
float angles[32];
for (uint i = 0; i < number_of_particles; i++)
{
    if ((particle_buffer[i].pos.y <= pos.y + sight && particle_buffer[i].pos.y >= pos.y - sight) && (particle_buffer[i].pos.x <= pos.x + sight && particle_buffer[i].pos.x >= pos.x - sight))//is it within sight square
    {
        nearby[i] = particle_buffer[i];
        count++;
    }
    if (count >= 32)
    {
        break;
    }

}

for (uint j = 0; j < count; j++)
{
    angles[j] = atan((pos.y - nearby[j].pos.y) / (pos.x - nearby[j].pos.x)); //angle in radians from current to next particle converted to degrees
}
```

and lines:

```
nearby[i] = particle_buffer[i];
```

```
angles[j] = atan((pos.y - nearby[j].pos.y) / (pos.x - nearby[j].pos.x)); //angle in radians from current to next particle converted to degrees
```

Both throw the same error about L values and array references:

```
Shader warning in 'hlsl_file': array reference cannot be used as an l-value; not natively addressable, forcing loop to unroll at kernel move at hlsl_file.compute(line_num) (on d3d11)
```

I've had a look through the Microsoft docs and some other forums, but I don't understand many of the solutions and most of the answers are for vertex shaders and not compute shaders like mine. The best guess that I can make is that it's because the arrays cannot accept varying index inputs when being assigned to another array but I'm not sure at all.

---

Edit:
after having had a look further on unity forums it looks like for some hardwares you can get this error by trying to address an array inside of a loop with an index variable that is not the loop variable (i or j), my code doesn't do this but maybe it's related?

Comment: The simple version is that an l-value is a value that represents a location in memory which can be assigned to (the "l" in the name refers to it being able to appear on the left side of an assignment). Array references by definition are not l-values, so you can't do what you are doing in this way. (Whether it's a vertex shader or compute shader is irrelevant in this case.)

Comment: @Abion47 that makes sense, i was trying to use the array like a python list, is there a way that i can assign a value to a specific index of an array without this referencing?

Answer (score 0, accepted):

I ended up just using a `RWStructuredBuffer` instead of an array, and everthing works perfectly. Not sure if this is efficient or not though.